# NextJS project: immediately send user to Auth0 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, auth0

I am a novice coder trying to work through a Typescript/NextJS project that uses Auth0.  It is currently set up to take users to a page (code below) that just has a login button that takes you to the Auth0 page.

This is an unnecessary step. How can I edit this to directly take the user to the Auth0 auth page upon navigating to the URL?

```
import "../styles/stripe.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "../styles/App.css";
import "../styles/index.css";
import "../styles/progress.css";

import { FC, StrictMode } from "react";
import { getCLS, getFCP, getFID, getLCP, getTTFB } from "web-vitals";
import { useUser, UserProvider } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../views/Header";

const SignInRequired: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();
  const router = useRouter();

  if (isLoading) return <div />;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container flex-col flex-center">
          <h1>AppCo</h1>
          <h2>Please sign in.</h2>
        
          <button
            className="card-test"
            onClick={() => router.push("/api/auth/login")}
          >Login</button>
          <p>Questions?</p> 
          <p><a href="mailto:hi@appco.com">hi@appco.com</a></p>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <StrictMode>
      <UserProvider>
        {/* Default SEO. */}
        <Head>
          <title>AppCo</title>
          <meta name="description" content="AppCo" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <div className="w-full">
          {/* Max layout width. */}
          <Header />
          <SignInRequired>

            <main className="w-full py-8">
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </main>
            <ToastContainer
              autoClose={2000}
            />
          </SignInRequired>

        </div>
      </UserProvider>
    </StrictMode>
  );
}

/**
 * Use Web Vitals.
 * 
 * @see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/measuring-performance
 */
export const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry) => {
  if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
    getCLS(onPerfEntry);
    getFID(onPerfEntry);
    getFCP(onPerfEntry);
    getLCP(onPerfEntry);
    getTTFB(onPerfEntry);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently the code is saying "if not a user, return the sign in button".
Instead of returning that sign in button, you can redirect using **`Router`** assuming this is your next.js file.

You'll need to also import router:

```js
import Router from 'next/router'
// or add push to your current line
import { useRouter, push } from "next/router";
```

```js
if (!user) {
    Router.push('/new-route')
    }
```

I'm afraid I'm not a next.js expert but hope this gets the job done for you! Good luck!